# The program flow going wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

In this code snippet the flow of program goes
 out of for loop first then only goes inside the block
resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset). 
The code prints the NSLog at the bottom first then executes the block inside the loop. What's happening here?

```
 ALAssetsLibrary *lib=[ALAssetsLibrary new];
    _sizeOfSelectedImage=0;
        for (int i=0; i<assets.count; i++) {
            ALAsset *asset=assets[i];
            FileOP *fileMgr=[[FileOP alloc]init];
            NSString *baseDir=[fileMgr GetDocumentDirectory];

            //STORING FILE INTO LOCAL

            [lib assetForURL:asset.defaultRepresentation.url
                 resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset){
                     ALAssetRepresentation *repr = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                     CGImageRef cgImg = [repr fullResolutionImage];
                     NSString *fname = repr.filename;
                     UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImg];
                     NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
                     [data writeToFile:[baseDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fname]
                            atomically:YES];
                     //FOR LOCAL URL OF THE IMAGE
                     //NSString *imageURL = [baseDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fname];
                     //UIImage *myImg =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageURL];
                     //NSLog(@"%@ URL OF IMAGE ",imageURL);
                     NSLog(@"Image %d has %d size",i,data.length);
                     _sizeOfSelectedImage   +=data.length;
                     NSLog(@"%d is the size",_sizeOfSelectedImage);

                 }
                             failureBlock:^(NSError *error){

                }];
        }

        NSLog(@"COPIED %lu FILE INTO LOCAL MEMORY AND TOTAL SIZE COPIED IS %d ",(unsigned    long)assets.count,_sizeOfSelectedImage);
```

Comment: I'm guessing the block is a block, it doesn't return first.

Comment: That is my problem. I dont know why it's going out of loop before executing the block. And it returns to the loop again.  I through breapoints. The program goes inside the for loop. And right where the block starts it goes out of loop. Prints NSLog at the bottom. Then returns back to the loop.

Comment: That's the way it's supposed to be though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:  will execute the load of asset asynchronously. That's why we first have the bottom NSLog executed and then in Block. If you want it to be executed synchronously, do it like this:

```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0) ^{
        ALAssetsLibrary *lib=[ALAssetsLibrary new];  
        _sizeOfSelectedImage=0;  

        dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();  

        for (int i=0;i<assets.count;i++) {  
                ALAsset *asset=assets[i];  
                FileOP *fileMgr=[[FileOP alloc]init];  
                NSString *baseDir=[fileMgr GetDocumentDirectory];  

                //STORING FILE INTO LOCAL
                dispatch_group_enter(group);  
                [lib assetForURL:asset.defaultRepresentation.url
                     resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset){
                         ALAssetRepresentation *repr = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                         CGImageRef cgImg = [repr fullResolutionImage];
                         NSString *fname = repr.filename;
                         UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImg];
                         NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
                         [data writeToFile:[baseDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fname]
                                atomically:YES];
                         //FOR LOCAL URL OF THE IMAGE
                         //NSString *imageURL = [baseDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fname];
                         //UIImage *myImg =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageURL];
                         //NSLog(@"%@ URL OF IMAGE ",imageURL);
                         NSLog(@"Image %d has %d size",i,data.length);
                         _sizeOfSelectedImage   +=data.length;
                         NSLog(@"%d is the size",_sizeOfSelectedImage);
                        dispatch_group_leave(group);  
                     }
                     failureBlock:^(NSError *error){
                                dispatch_group_leave(group);  
                    }];
            }
            dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);  
            NSLog(@"COPIED %lu FILE INTO LOCAL MEMORY AND TOTAL SIZE COPIED IS %d ",(unsigned    long)assets.count,_sizeOfSelectedImage);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 // Do your call back on main thread here
            });
    });
```

Edit1: Enhanced answer from Ken

```
ALAssetsLibrary *lib=[ALAssetsLibrary new];
_sizeOfSelectedImage=0;

dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

for (int i=0;i<assets.count;i++) {
    ALAsset *asset=assets[i];
    FileOP *fileMgr=[[FileOP alloc]init];
    NSString *baseDir=[fileMgr GetDocumentDirectory];

    //STORING FILE INTO LOCAL
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    [lib assetForURL:asset.defaultRepresentation.url
         resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset){
             ALAssetRepresentation *repr = [asset defaultRepresentation];
             CGImageRef cgImg = [repr fullResolutionImage];
             NSString *fname = repr.filename;
             UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImg];
             NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
             [data writeToFile:[baseDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fname]
                    atomically:YES];
             //FOR LOCAL URL OF THE IMAGE
             //NSString *imageURL = [baseDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fname];
             //UIImage *myImg =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageURL];
             //NSLog(@"%@ URL OF IMAGE ",imageURL);
             NSLog(@"Image %d has %d size",i,data.length);
             _sizeOfSelectedImage   +=data.length;
             NSLog(@"%d is the size",_sizeOfSelectedImage);
             dispatch_group_leave(group);
         }
        failureBlock:^(NSError *error){
            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        }];
}
dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Do your call back on main thread here
    NSLog(@"COPIED %lu FILE INTO LOCAL MEMORY AND TOTAL SIZE COPIED IS %d ",(unsigned    long)assets.count,_sizeOfSelectedImage);

    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: That was my first thought! How to make it synchronous and correct the flow of program any idea?

Comment: Don't try to make asynchronous methods synchronous. Change your program logic to handle the ssynchronicity. In this case, put the final log into the result block.

Comment: @KenThomases The final log is the result of multiple result blocks, so Simon's answer is the correct approach.

Comment: @PrajeetShrestha How long did you wait? The code in the answer will wait forever for the requests to complete.  You could change it to `dispatch_group_wait(group,dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,10000000))` to wait for 10 seconds - check the result of `dispatch_group_wait` - if it is non-zero then the timeout was reached

Comment: Since I want to notify users about the size of image after the block is completed, and the block is inside the for loop. They will get multiple notification if I put notification there! The NSlog would be replaced by alert view. Something very wrong abt the program logic here. I need to fix it. Should alert the user before copying the image into the application folder :)

Comment: I waited for more than 10 sec . I will check it out! again.

Comment: I tried putting dispatch_group_wait(group,dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,10000000)), the the code responded same way as the beginning.

Comment: @Paulw11 More of the times, we use DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER if our logic is not discardable, so timeout option is only used when we don't care the operation can be finished or not. More acceeptable way is to move the code to another thread to avoid the blocking of main thread, and then execute call back on main thread after all actions finished.

Comment: I agree DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER is correct, but I was suggesting a debugging process to see if there was a problem causing the hang.  I agree also that the whole loop should be executed off the main thread. You should update your answer to do this and delete your other answer.  Also note for the OP's benefit that if the final action is to be an `Alert` then that will need to be executed on the main thread

Comment: Thanks for the help @Simon. The above code worked very well. Sad I could only accept ur answer and not vote up since I dont have much reputation :). On the last line it should be dispatch_main_queue(). For the newbies in objective C like me :).

Comment: @Paulw11, you're right that I didn't notice the loop. However, that means the right answer is to use `dispatch_group_notify()` rather than `dispatch_group_wait()`. That avoids trying to make the code synchronous.