# Load images asyncroniously to the array using GCD

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, grand-central-dispatch

I try to use panoramaGL framework to show panorama. The server-side returns several tile images for every side of cube panorama. So I need to load this images asyncroniously into the array and after this I need to make a big side texture from this images - the code for the first part of this task is:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{

    int columnCount;
    int rowCount;

    NSString *side;

    if ([level  isEqual: @"3"]) {
        columnCount = 1;
        rowCount = 1;
    } else if ([level  isEqual: @"2"]) {
        columnCount = 2;
        rowCount = 2;
```

... here I prepare the url string parameters

```
    if (face == PLCubeFaceOrientationFront)
        side = @"F";
    else if (face == PLCubeFaceOrientationBack)
        side = @"B";
```

... here I prepare the url string parameters

```
    self.tileArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:columnCount];

    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnCount; columnIndex++) {
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++) {

            NSString *tileUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_%d", columnIndex, rowIndex];

            NSMutableArray *tileUrlComponents = [NSMutableArray array];

            [tileUrlComponents addObject: panoramaData[@"id"]];
            [tileUrlComponents addObject: side];
            [tileUrlComponents addObject: level];
            [tileUrlComponents addObject: tileUrl];

            NSString *tileIdString = [tileUrlComponents componentsJoinedByString:@"/"];

            NSString *panoramaIdUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://SOMEURL=%@", tileIdString];

            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:panoramaIdUrlString];
            NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *res, NSData *data, NSError *err) {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    NSMutableArray *array = [self.tileArray objectAtIndex:columnIndex];
                    [array replaceObjectAtIndex:rowIndex withObject:image];
                    [self.tileArray addObject:array];
                });
            }];

            NSLog(@"The URL for the %@ tile is %@", tileUrl, tileIdString);
        }
    }
});
```

The main question - how can I understand, that my array is loaded  - and I can now work with the images in it. The second question is that I get the empty array now unfortunately. Any help?

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857150/the-program-flow-going-wrong/24857220?noredirect=1#comment38602097_24857220 You need to use the same technique - use a dispatch group to know when all of your asynchronous loads are complete

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you considered using operations.

This is how I would do:

1. Create `NSOperation` for each request (make sure in your code the operation stays alive until it has finished loading)
2. Add each operation to `NSOperationQueue`. (By calling `-operations` you can see how many operations are in progress)
3. If you implement `NSOperationQueue` on back thread you can use `-waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` (this method blocks current thread until all your images have been downloaded) and then execute your code to display images. You can alternatively add all `NSOperation's` to `NSArray` and add to `NSOperationQueue` by using `-(void)addOperations:(NSArray *)ops waitUntilFinished:(BOOL)wait`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,  0ul);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{

```
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: ImageURL];
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: data];


            [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 100) writeToFile: imagePath atomically: YES];


        });
    });
```

where imagePath ia a path in your applications directory..You can make a temporary directory and store the images there…and while retrieving you can just use the simple method as..

UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithCOntentsOFFile:imagePath];.

It worked for me…just give it a try